# Regex should not be recognized for special characters

Tags: regex

I want the regex not to be recognized, should be a special character before, between and after the regex.

My Regex:

```
\b([t][\W_]*?)+([e][\W_]*?)+([s][\W_]*?)+([t][\W_]*?)*?\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/zKg2eR/1

Example:

#test, te+st, t'est or =test etc.

I hope I could bring it across reasonably understandable.

Comment: The explaination on the right in regex101 explains it to you: *"\W matches any non-word character (equivalent to [^a-zA-Z0-9_])"*. So don't use \W otherwise you allow any non-a-zA-Z0-9 character. As to before and after: Use `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end. You can see their meaning in regex101 on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match a word character excluding an underscore, you can write it as `[^\W_]` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

You don't need a character class for a single char `[t]` and you are repeating the groups as well, which you don't have to when you want to match a form of `test`

If the words are on a single line, you can append anchors `^` and `$`

```
^(t[^\W_]*)(e[^\W_]*)(s[^\W_]*)(t[^\W_]*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h9r35k/1)

As you selected *golang* in the regex tester, you can not use lookarounds. Instead you can use an alternation to match either a whitespace char or the start/end of the string.

Then capture the whole match in another capture group.

```
(?:^|\s)((t[^\W_]*)(e[^\W_]*)(s[^\W_]*)(t[^\W_]*))(?:$|\s)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G6z3s0/1)

Comment: You are the best. How would that look with a "lookaround", that is, if I now take ".NET(#C)" instead of "Golang"?

Comment: @ALLTON If you want to keep the separate capture groups like this `(?<!\S)(t[^\W_]*)(e[^\W_]*)(s[^\W_]*)(t[^\W_]*)(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/I8N5CL/1 If you want the match only then `(?<!\S)t[^\W_]*e[^\W_]*s[^\W_]*t[^\W_]*(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/8Z4vYr/1

Comment: @ALLTON The mechanics are the same, only the first one has capture groups using parenthesis like  `(t[^\W_]*)` where you could for example using code extract that group value like group 1, group 2 etc..The second pattern has only the whole full match. The lookarounds `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` assert whitespace boundaries to the left and the right.

Comment: @ALLTON A regex can not "Ignore" matches in a consecutive match. You can either capture separate parts with groups, or get separate matches which you would have to join back together afterwards. You can also first match, and the replace what you don't want with an empty string.